# Is there any way to run a method or intent when a notification or message is received in background in android?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, message

I am working on an application on which i want to run a method when a message or notification is received from another device.
Notification or method will be send from the sender device and method should run on the Receiver device.
Please guide me . Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to listen notifications using Notification Listener Service . And check whether the notification is for your app and then call method

Comment: Thanks but please can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: I dont want to call method on notification click. I want to call method in background when notification is received. Is there any way?

Comment: NotificationListenerService is a service and There is a method onNotificationPosted() which will be invoked when notification is received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the notification is received, You will be notified if you have used **Notification Listener Service**

```
@TargetApi(18)
public class NotificationsListenerService extends android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService {



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerConnected() {

        Log.d("NotificationListener", "listenerconnected");
    }


    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
      //here check notification and call method


    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.d("NotificationListener","removed "+ sbn.getPackageName() + " notification");
    }
```

To use this service , You need **Notification Access**

```
        String enabledNotificationListeners = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners");
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        if (enabledNotificationListeners == null || !enabledNotificationListeners.contains(packageName)) {
               startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"), 13);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turn on Notification Access for \"App\"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        startService(this, NotificationsListenerService.class);
    }
```